# C# HttpClient POST request handle response

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I need to make POST request to API which receives the parameters username, password, and productId.I created that part and it's working fine, but how can I handle response, when the send parameters are correct API returns status 200 and product object. In other case when send parameters are wrong API returns 200 and json object like bellow:

```
{
    "Username": {
        "Messages": [
            "The Username field is required."
        ]
    },
    "Password": {
        "Messages": [
            "The Password field is required."
        ]
    },
    "ProductId": {
        "Messages": [
            "The productId field is required."
        ]
    }
}
```

so how can I handle somethnig like this.

This is my code for POST request:

```
public async Task<string> PostProductId(string path)
{
    using (var client = GetHttpClient())
    {
        string content = null;
        try
        {
            string endpoint = path;

            string requestJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bodyObject);
            HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(requestJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            var response = await client.PostAsync(endpoint, httpContent);

            content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        }
        catch (HttpRequestException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR: " + ex.Message);
            return null
        }
        return content;
    }
}
```

Comment: Define "handle". Do you want to parse the JSON?

Comment: you say: "when send parameters are wrong API returns 200". so are you always getting the 200 response and no exceptions?

Comment: it should return BadRequest http status code 400. In that case try to add these properties to your object, but if the structure of the response is diff will have to add a content checking then deserialize as object or just copy json to property like string Errors?

Comment: if you cannot change the existing API (i.e. because it's provided by 3rd party) to return an actual error code you just have to check if the content contains "something unexpected" like you showed

Comment: You should not be `using` HttpClient. Instead use HttpClientFactory to create new instances. Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Answer (score 1):

To return both status and object you can use `IHttpActionResult`.

You can do some thing like this with out testing it:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostProductId(string path)
{
    using (var client = GetHttpClient())
    {
        string content = null;
        try
        {
            string endpoint = path;

            string requestJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bodyObject);
            HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(requestJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            var response = await client.PostAsync(endpoint, httpContent);

            content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        }
        catch (HttpRequestException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR: " + ex.Message);
            return InternalServerError(ex);
        }
        return Ok(content);
    }
}
```

Some Ref:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/action-results
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/webapi?view=aspnetcore-2.2